# Can the verb "explain" be used as an intransitive verb?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Could a student interrupt their teacher and ask:"Could you explain please?" without specifying what, adding "that" or "that to me" or "what you're saying?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

You can say: **could  you  please  explain in detail?**

**Could you please explain further?**

I attached a link which shows how explain can be used in different ways

https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/explain